# Two ternary operators spread into one inline style giving 'Failed to compile' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use two ternary operators in one line for a style element inline. This is the code I am trying to pass:

```
style={{ ...display: mode === "single" ? "none" : "block",
         ...display: gradientSelected === 'radial' ? "block" : "none" }}
```

"mode" and "gradientSelected" are states, these are the states:

```
const [gradientSelected, setGradientSelected] = useState("linear")
const [mode, setMode] = useState("single")
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Is there a better way to use two ternary operators in one line?

Also, is there a way to have two conditions in one ternary function? In my example, `if mode === single AND gradientSelected === linear, display none`.

Comment: spread operator '...' is for values, you're putting it before a key name. That won't be valid syntax. Can you explain the logic you're expecting?

Comment: ternary conditions work the same as other conditions. `true && true ? 'this' : 'not that'`, so yes you can have as many conditions as you want in your ternary condition.

Comment: Basically, I want two IF statements inline. One is to check if the 'mode' state is 'single', if so, display none. Although, if its 'gradient', display block. Now, once it is gradient mode, if gradientSelected is linear, display none, if its radial, display block. That is what I want to happen

Comment: You can nest ternary operations as well: `false ? 'not this' : (false ? 'not this either' : 'this')` but its bad practice because of readability.

Comment: Please don't use multiple ternary statements inline, instead use a computed function if at all possible. Sincerely, the guy who has to do your code review.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors - sincerely, the guy who has to maintain your code 2 years from now because there wasn't a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to spread an object, it needs to be an object first:

```js
const mode = "single";
const gradientSelected = "foo";

const style = {
  ...{ display: mode === "single" ? "none" : "block" },
  ...{ display: gradientSelected === 'radial' ? "block" : "none" }
};
         
console.log(style);
```

Note that the second object will *always* win though, so I'm not sure this is correct for what you are trying to achieve.

I think this might be more suited:

```js
const mode = "single";
const gradientSelected = "foo";

const style = {
  display: mode === "single" && gradientSelected === "linear" ? "none" : "block"
};
         
console.log(style);
```

Comment: This works! although, is it best practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: So the problem is the first ternary is basically useless, it'll always be overwritten by the second. I suspect what you really want is to combine both variables into one ternary

Comment: I added an additional example that might help you get closer to what you're going for, which is using two conditions in one ternary operator.

Comment: Although, the exact same code but with the && operator, doesn't work, any idea why that is? specifically this: "display: mode === "single" && gradientSelected === "linear" ? "none" : "block","

Comment: That sound work just fine! Is that definitely the right condition? mode = single AND gradient = linear, display: none, otherwise display: block?

Comment: Yes! Basically, in dummy text, IF 'mode' === 'single' AND 'gradient' === 'linear' THEN 'display: none' thats exactly the way it should be, otherwise, if any of those conditions are false, display block.

Comment: This code works: mode === "single" || gradientSelected === "linear" ? "none" : "block", but this doesn't for some reason, mode === "single" && gradientSelected === "linear" ? "none" : "block"

Comment: I added that last code to my example and it seems to work okay

Comment: Hmm, I'll do more debugging to find the root cause. Thank you anyway! I will mark your answer as correct